# From BigInt to HexString in littleEndian in SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, hex, bigint

I have the following code in Sql Server 2019.

```
 declare @Id bigint
 declare @HexId varchar(50)

set @Id = 98360090175733911

set @HexId = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(VARBINARY(16),@Id),2)

select @HexId
```

This is working, but the result must be in little endian.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Kind regards,
Bert Berrevoets.

I have tried the reverse function, but this was not ok.

Answer (score 0):

to get the string i used the internal function `master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr`it seems to be the format you wanted

```
 declare @Id bigint
 declare @HexId varchar(50)

set @Id = 98360090175733911

set @HexId = master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(BINARY(16), REVERSE(CONVERT(BINARY(16), @Id))))

select @HexId
```

Get you

```
0x9700001bfb715d010000000000000000
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, vacation always nice :)
Yes, that's what  i need, thanks you!